# How to Shopify Display Exc VAT Price for Product Variants?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-template, liquid-template

Been working on a website where I want two prices to appear on the product page.

1. Default Inc VAT Price
2. Exc VAT Price, which would be the default price divided by 1.2

We're using the enterprise theme and I've managed to get it to display on the product page by amending the main-product.liquid file.

```
          {%- when 'price' -%}
            <div class="product-info__block product-info__block--sm product-price" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <div class="product-info__price">
                {% render 'price', product: product, use_variant: true %}
                <p> {{ product.price | divided_by: 1.2 | money }} ex. VAT </p>
              </div>
```

However, the problem I have now is that the price doesn't update when clicking on different variations that the product has, the default price does update, just not the Exc VAT price I've added in.

Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit `price.liquid` file.

### Your calculation

```js
assign tax_price = target.price | divided_by: 1.2
assign tax_money_price = tax_price | money
```

[image: price calculation]

### Your markup

```html
<div class="price__regular tax__price">
  <span class="tax-included-price price-item price-item--regular">
    {{ tax_money_price }} excluding VAT.
  </span>
</div>
```

[image: markup]

### Result

[image: result]

if any doubts please comment

Comment: Hi @hardik-satasiya

This doesn't seem to work for the enterprise theme,

Adding the code lines to the price.liquid file and then adding the code to the main-product.liquid file just displays "excluding VAT" on the page but no price.

Comment: Here is my price.liquid file 

`{%- liquid
  if use_variant
    assign variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant
  else
    assign use_variant = false
    assign variant = product.variants | sort: 'price' | first
  endif

  assign available = variant.available | default: false
  assign compare_at_price = variant.compare_at_price
  assign price = variant.price | default: 1999
  assign tax_price = variant.price | divided_by: 1.2
  assign tax_money_price = tax_price | money
-%}
`

Comment: hmm, it seems your code is in a separate file try moving them in single file, which means try to use price. liquid for markup as well. or if possible share me access i can check and fix for you or change markup so UI stays same but price can be updated.

Comment: Hi Hardik, what’s your email? I’ll send you an invitation. Thanks

Comment: its hardik_satasiya@yahoo.com

Comment: Hi, just sent you an invitation. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I will check once I get free 

Comment: It seems there was JS involved, added code, and implemented it, you can check it now. By the way, you can WhatsApp me if needed -> +91 9724182849